# How to change a fragment and let the previous fragment not be clickable in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

I have a Fragment with a ListView, if a listItem is clicked it has to go to the a NewFragment. I do this with:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
   NewFragment newFrag = NewFragment.newInstance("data1","data2");
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
      .replace(R.id.container, newFrag, this.getTag())
      .addToBackStack(null)
      .commit();
}
```

It shows the NewFragment and the ListView is not visable, but it is still clickable. How do I achieve that the ListView is not visable and not clickable?

Comment: The ListView is defined in XML

Comment: Show your xml please, It would help to see how the `R.id.cotainer` is defined.

Comment: Make the ParentLayout of your NewFragment clickable to handle the click events. Add this line to the ParentLayout of your NewFragment >> android:clickable="true"

Comment: Thx u that was the solution!